# SSIS, YYYYMMDD date format, from flat file to SQLServer 2008R2 table (OLE DB Destination)

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a flat file with dates in `YYYYMMDD` format, e.g. `19990131`. I'm reading it with Flat File Source, column has default setting (`DT_STR`, width `50`)... When I try to insert data via OLE DB Destination to a table with Date column I got the error: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

What is the cause of it? SQLServer easily understands YYYYMMDD format...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server may understand it, but SSIS doesn't. Note this comment from the SSIS [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the
>   transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of
>   YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO
>   format.

SSIS is trying to interpret `YYYYMMDD` based on the locale of the flat file connector, which may work for some locales but apparently not for yours. As you discovered, changing it to `YYYY-MM-DD` works, because SSIS considers that format to be unambiguous (you could also change the locale of the flat file connector, of course, although that might affect other data).

Unfortunately, this behaviour is the exact opposite in SQL Server itself, at least for the [`datetime` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx): `YYYYMMDD` is unambiguous and `YYYY-MM-DD` is ambiguous. On the other hand, for the newer [`date` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) both `YYYYMMDD` and `YYYY-MM-DD` are unambiguous in SQL Server.

Comment: Exactly the kind of explanation I wanted to see (difference between SSIS and SQL Server was confusing). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I change `YYYYMMDD` to `YYYY-MM-DD` before putting data into table everything works fine.  I will accept this as an answer if nobody gives another, better solution. Maybe mine is prone to localization errors?